# Chrome extension not loading background script sometimes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am having problem with chrome extensions but only sometimes.

This is my simple manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "WorkPuls",
  "description": "Test extension",
  "version": "1.1",
  "icons": {  "16": "icon16.png",
              "48": "icon48.png",
              "128": "icon128.png" },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["test.js"]
  }
}
```

Most of the time test.js is loaded correctly but sometimes it is loaded as blank file. Does anyone have suggestion for this?

Test.js:

```
function sendActiveTabUrl(url){
    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:13374');
    connection.onopen = function(){
        connection.send(url);
        connection.close();
    }
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if( changeInfo.status == "complete")
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            sendActiveTabUrl(tab.url);
        });
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(info) {
    var tab = chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, function(tab) {
        sendActiveTabUrl(tab.url);
    });
});

chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(windowId) {
    if(windowId == -1){
        return;
    }
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(windowId, function(tab){
        sendActiveTabUrl(tab.url);
    });
});

setInterval(function(){
    chrome.windows.getAll({'populate':true}, function(windows){
        for(var i in windows){
            if(windows[i].focused){
                chrome.tabs.getSelected(windows[i].id, function(tab){
                    sendActiveTabUrl(tab.url);
                });
            }
        }
    })
},1500);
```

Comment: Could you provide the `test.js` code?

Comment: too many days without including the code so flagging to close

Comment: Sorry I will write it right now. I was out of town when received notification. Sorry.

Comment: No idea what could be the problem. Please describe "loaded as a blank file" symptom better.

Comment: I am also having this issue but have noticed that the file is only "blank" or "empty" when it is not served from my local machine. ie. When the extension is installed from the webstore rather than from me just dragging the files from my machine into chrome://extensions. I think it might be something to do with the content policy but unsure. Did you work it out?